# Valid algorithm input strings for Node.js' crypto.createSign()

Tags: javascript, node.js, openssl, cryptography, digital-signature

I'm using node's crypto signatures for a project, and have been trying to consider the ups and downs of various algorithms. The description of `crypto.createSign()` reads as the following:

> Creates and returns a Sign object that uses the given algorithm. On recent  OpenSSL releases, `openssl list-public-key-algorithms` will display the available signing algorithms. One example is 'RSA-SHA256'.

Unfortunately, "RSA-SHA256" isn't one of the output values of `openssl list-public-key-algorithms` (shown below).

So what are the valid values of this function, or how are they extracted from the list below?

```
OpenSSL list result:
Name: OpenSSL RSA method
        Type: Builtin Algorithm
        OID: rsaEncryption
        PEM string: RSA
Name: rsa
        Type: Alias to rsaEncryption
Name: OpenSSL PKCS#3 DH method
        Type: Builtin Algorithm
        OID: dhKeyAgreement
        PEM string: DH
Name: dsaWithSHA
        Type: Alias to dsaEncryption
Name: dsaEncryption-old
        Type: Alias to dsaEncryption
Name: dsaWithSHA1-old
        Type: Alias to dsaEncryption
Name: dsaWithSHA1
        Type: Alias to dsaEncryption
Name: OpenSSL DSA method
        Type: Builtin Algorithm
        OID: dsaEncryption
        PEM string: DSA
Name: OpenSSL EC algorithm
        Type: Builtin Algorithm
        OID: id-ecPublicKey
        PEM string: EC
Name: OpenSSL HMAC method
        Type: Builtin Algorithm
        OID: hmac
        PEM string: HMAC
Name: OpenSSL CMAC method
        Type: Builtin Algorithm
        OID: cmac
        PEM string: CMAC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Node documentation is wrong. For `crypto.createSign()`, use the following command to list the possibilities:

```
openssl list-message-digest-algorithms
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some brute-forcing and good guessing, the structure of valid algorithm input strings appears to make little sense. There are many exceptions to what begins to look like a rule. If a public key algorithm is omitted, RSA appears to be the default. Below is an incomplete list of the values that DO work:

Public Key Algorithm alone:

- "DSA"

Hash alone:

- "MD4"
- "MD5"
- "SHA"
- "DSS1"
- "MDC2"
- "SHA1"
- "SHA224"
- "SHA256"
- "SHA512"

Public-Key-Algorithm-Hash pairs:

- "RSA-MD4"
- "RSA-MD5"
- "RSA-SHA"
- "RSA-MDC2"
- "RSA-SHA1"
- "RSA-SHA224"
- "RSA-SHA256"
- "RSA-SHA512"
- "DSA-SHA"
- "DSA-SHA1"

I'm not a cryptographer, so it may be possible that RSA requires explicit hash choice, or that DSA is not compatible with sha512 or md5, but I find it more likely that these inconsistencies are caused by openSSL's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Run `crypto.getHashes()` to get the list of available signing algorithms.

For example, if you run it in Node `v8.15.0` then you get:

```
[ 'DSA',
  'DSA-SHA',
  'DSA-SHA1',
  'DSA-SHA1-old',
  'RSA-MD4',
  'RSA-MD5',
  'RSA-MDC2',
  'RSA-RIPEMD160',
  'RSA-SHA',
  'RSA-SHA1',
  'RSA-SHA1-2',
  'RSA-SHA224',
  'RSA-SHA256',
  'RSA-SHA384',
  'RSA-SHA512',
  'dsaEncryption',
  'dsaWithSHA',
  'dsaWithSHA1',
  'dss1',
  'ecdsa-with-SHA1',
  'md4',
  'md4WithRSAEncryption',
  'md5',
  'md5WithRSAEncryption',
  'mdc2',
  'mdc2WithRSA',
  'ripemd',
  'ripemd160',
  'ripemd160WithRSA',
  'rmd160',
  'sha',
  'sha1',
  'sha1WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha224',
  'sha224WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha256',
  'sha256WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha384',
  'sha384WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha512',
  'sha512WithRSAEncryption',
  'shaWithRSAEncryption',
  'ssl2-md5',
  'ssl3-md5',
  'ssl3-sha1',
  'whirlpool' ]
```

In Node `v10.15.1` you will get:

```
[ 'RSA-MD4',
  'RSA-MD5',
  'RSA-MDC2',
  'RSA-RIPEMD160',
  'RSA-SHA1',
  'RSA-SHA1-2',
  'RSA-SHA224',
  'RSA-SHA256',
  'RSA-SHA384',
  'RSA-SHA512',
  'blake2b512',
  'blake2s256',
  'md4',
  'md4WithRSAEncryption',
  'md5',
  'md5-sha1',
  'md5WithRSAEncryption',
  'mdc2',
  'mdc2WithRSA',
  'ripemd',
  'ripemd160',
  'ripemd160WithRSA',
  'rmd160',
  'sha1',
  'sha1WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha224',
  'sha224WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha256',
  'sha256WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha384',
  'sha384WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha512',
  'sha512WithRSAEncryption',
  'ssl3-md5',
  'ssl3-sha1',
  'whirlpool' ]
```

Comment: so it looks like node v10 got a few of them removed. For example DSA-SHA1. How do I get them back without switching to node v8?